# splitting the first number from a string into another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with property information. Currently the property type column reads "3 bedroom apartment" etc. I would like put the number of bedrooms and property type into two separate columns - bedroom_no "3" and property_type "apartment", and drop "bedroom".

I have tried: """ df['bedroom_no'] = df['property'].str[:1] """ (property being the name of the column which contains the relevant information. But I am currently getting no result.

How would I solve this?

Comment: Are there any shared pattern in different property values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas has a ton of great string methods. For the specific example you give, you can use `.str.extract()` to get the integer and `.str.split()` to get the housing type. If your `property` column contains more info or info in a different order, then update your question with specific and representative examples.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'property': ['3 bedroom apartment', '5 bedroom house']})

df['bedroom_no'] = df['property'].str.extract('(\d+)')
df['property_type'] = df['property'].str.split(' ').str.get(2)

print(df)
```

Console output:

```
              property bedroom_no property_type
0  3 bedroom apartment          3     apartment
1      5 bedroom house          5         house
```

Comment: Great that has worked thank you.